# 'mat-toolbar' is not a known element:

Tags: angular, typescript

Getting error while running karma tests
'mat-toolbar' is not a known element:
'mat-toolbar' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-toolbar' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-toolbar' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("[ERROR ->]
  The Deccan Chronical 
app.module.ts

```
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MaterialModule } from './material.module';
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Ng2SearchPipeModule } from 'ng2-search-filter';
import {SearchComponent} from './search/search.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, HomeComponent,SearchComponent,MatToolbarModule],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MaterialModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    Ng2SearchPipeModule,
    FormsModule,
    MatToolbarModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`MatToolbarModule` should be part of the `imports` array rather than your `declarations`.

It is a Module, so they live in **imports**.

Comment: Just remove `MatToolbaModule` from your `declarations` array.